# Draw swipe with UIBezierPath in UIImageView

Tags: uiview, uiimageview, drawing, drawrect, uibezierpath

I am trying to draw something in UIImageView..I am able to draw without problems in UIView using the following code:

```
@implementation DrawView
{
    UIBezierPath *path; 
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder 
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO]; 
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [path setLineWidth:2.0]; 
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];
}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
    [path moveToPoint:p];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
    [path addLineToPoint:p]; // (4)
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

This skips imageview.. What I need is the opposite. I wanna draw in a uiimageview and skip uiview.. How can I do that? Thanks in advance..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The drawing surface needs to be a parent in the hierarchy of this view set.  That way you can draw on the parent view, while the image lies underneath.

```
-Main View
--Drawing View
---UIImageView
```

Comment: and if you need the Drawing view to be of the size of the image view just resize its bounds/frame to be that of its child imageview.